# How to send selected data on datagridview to a textbox in a seperate form?

Tags: c#, ms-access, datagridview

I have a datagridview that stores users' information, and it is linked to a ms-access database. I want them to be able to select on the row in the datagridview, then open the "edit profile" form with the data from that row already inserted into the text boxes. Right now I have to insert the ID# into the first row, so it can read which row I am referring to. Here is what I have so far.

```
{
        ConnectToDataBase();
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            textBox1.Text = 
            textBox2.Text = reader.GetValue(2).ToString();
            textBox3.Text = reader.GetValue(3).ToString();
            textBox4.Text = reader.GetValue(4).ToString();
            textBox5.Text = reader.GetValue(5).ToString();
            comboBox1.Text = reader.GetValue(6).ToString();
            comboBox2.Text = reader.GetValue(7).ToString();
            textBox6.Text = reader.GetValue(8).ToString();
        }
        //string query = "update Profiles set [PROFILE NAME]='" + textBox1.Text + "', [LOGIN EMAIL]='" + textBox2.Text + "', [PASSWORD]='" + textBox3.Text + "', [FULL NAME]='" + textBox4.Text + "', [CARD NUMBER]='" + textBox5.Text + "', [EXP MONTH]='" + comboBox1.Text + "', [EXP YEAR]='" + comboBox2.Text + "', CVV='" + textBox6.Text + "' where  ID='" + Convert.ToInt32(textBox7.Text) + "'";
        string query = "update Profiles set [PROFILE NAME]= @Profile, [LOGIN EMAIL]= @Email, [PASSWORD]= @Pass, [FULL NAME]= @Name, [CARD NUMBER]= @Card, [EXP MONTH]= @EXPM, [EXP YEAR]= @EXPY, CVV= @CVV where ID = @Id";
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Profile", textBox1.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", textBox2.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pass", textBox3.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", textBox4.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Card", textBox5.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EXPM", comboBox1.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EXPY", comboBox2.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CVV", textBox6.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", textBox7.Text);
        command.CommandText = query;
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        RefreshDBConnection();
        connection.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Profile Edited");
        this.Close();
```

Thank you!

Comment: What is the problem? Where you get an error? Only a guess: What type is ID of? Is it an `int`? Then you have to add a int value as parameter @ID to your update command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your question is a mess. Second, your code is a mess. Anyway i will explain you a bit down here.

First from you question title `How to send selected data on datagridview to a textbox in a seperate form?`
 i guess you have `datagirdview` in one form and you want to send data of selected row into other form.

Here are two cases:

First case is if you are sending data when opening new form. So user select row, then press button and opens up another form which need to have data from that row.

To do this you will make use of forms `constructor`

```
public partial class SecondForm : Form
{
    public SecondForm(int userId, string userName)
    {
        InitializeComponents();

        MessageBox.Show("User ID you passed is " + userId + " and it's name is " + userName);
    }
}
```

Now we have changed our constructor to requires values we call this form from first one (with datagridview) like this:

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //This is event of button click

    if(yourDataGridView.SelectedRows.Count < 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You must select one user!");
        return;
    }

    DataGridViewRow row = yourDataGridView.SelectedRows[0]; // We will select first selected row. If there are multiple selected rows we will select just first one

    int uid = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["ColumnThatContainsUserId"].Value);
    string uname = row.Cells["ColumnThatContainsUserName"].Value.ToString();

    //I am using `using` since `Form` is disposable class and instead of later doing sf.Dispose() i use `using`. This way we take care of perfomance
    using(SecondForm sf = new SecondForm(uid, uname))
    {
        sf.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Now i have passed it like `int, string` but what i would really do is create custom class for user and pass it.

In case you have already opened first form (one with dataGridView) and also you have opened second one you could do it like this.

First we need to make public accessible function in second form which will update your textboxes.

```
public partial class SecondForm : Form
{
    public SecondForm()
    {
        // All your code
    }

    public void SwitchUser(int userId, string userName)
    {
        textbox1.Text = userId.ToString();
        textbox2.Text = userName;
    }
}
```

Now we have function which will update our textboxes with passed values. Now we need to access that function from first form

```
public partial class FirstForm : Form
{
    private SecondForm sf; //Declaring it so it is accessible from whole first form class

    private int lastSelectedRow = -1; //Will use it later

    public FirstForm()
    {
        //All your code
    }

    private void dataGridView_CellClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //This event fires every time user click cell

        if(sf == null)
        {
            //This means our second form has not been initialized so maybe show message to user and return or open it up

            //First solution
            sf = new SecondForm();
            sf.Show();

            //Second solution
            MessageBox.Show("Second form is not initialized!");
            return;
        }

        //I would here check if(sf.Visible) and if it is not i would sf.Show();

        //We check if same row has been selected. If it does then we do nothing
        if(dataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Index == lastSelectedRow)
            return;

        int uid = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["ColumnThatContainsUserId"].Value);
        string uname = row.Cells["ColumnThatContainsUserName"].Value.ToString();

       sf.SwitchUser(uid, uname); //Accessing through global variable

       lastSelectedRow = dataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Index;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! I'm sorry this is my first c# program, and I've only been coding for maybe two weeks, that's why everything is so messy. Anyway, I have the text boxes filled, but if I end up not saving the edit changes, and instead want to close out of the second form, I get this error: System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Comment: I did some tweaking and I solved it, thank you! Works well now!